# Cartesian product of different size

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I can have the cartesian product of lists thanks to the `itertools.product()` function:

```
lists = [['A', 'B'], ['1', '2'], ['x', 'y']]
combinations = itertools.product(*lists)
# [('A', '1', 'x'), ('A', '2', 'y'), ..., ('B', '2', 'y')]
```

What I want is the same thing but with all different sizes:

```
all_comb = magicfunction(lists)
# [('A', '1', 'x'), ..., ('B', '2', 'y'), ('A', '1'), ('A', '2'), ... ('2', 'y'), ... ('y')]
```

I can't see the one obvious way to do it.

I would need a method that could let me set the minimum AND maximum size of the tuples (I deal with long lists and need only combinations of sizes from 7 to 3, the number of lists and their size vary).

My lists are more like:

```
lists = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2'], ['x', 'y', 'z', 'u'], ...] # size may go to a few dozens
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66789371

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import product, combinations
>>> lists = [['A', 'B'], ['1', '2'], ['x', 'y']]
>>> for i in xrange(2, len(lists)+1):
    for c in combinations(lists, i):
        print list(product(*c))
...         
[('A', '1'), ('A', '2'), ('B', '1'), ('B', '2')]
[('A', 'x'), ('A', 'y'), ('B', 'x'), ('B', 'y')]
[('1', 'x'), ('1', 'y'), ('2', 'x'), ('2', 'y')]
[('A', '1', 'x'), ('A', '1', 'y'), ('A', '2', 'x'), ('A', '2', 'y'), ('B', '1', 'x'), ('B', '1', 'y'), ('B', '2', 'x'), ('B', '2', 'y')]
```

Comment: I misunderstood the purpose of the second argument of combinaisons() due to the fact that the documentation uses strings as iterables in their examples. There was an obvious way to do it. Thx. I guess I can set the maximum size just by restricting the range.

Answer (score 2):

Just chain several products together, based on combinations of smaller size:

```
from itertools import chain, product, combinations

def ranged_product(*lists, **start_stop):
    start, stop = start_stop.get('start', len(lists)), start_stop.get('stop', 0)
    return chain.from_iterable(product(*comb)
                               for size in xrange(start, stop - 1, -1)
                               for comb in combinations(lists, r=size))
```

Demo:

```
>>> lists = [['A', 'B'], ['1', '2'], ['x', 'y']]
>>> for prod in ranged_product(stop=2, *lists):
...     print prod
... 
('A', '1', 'x')
('A', '1', 'y')
('A', '2', 'x')
('A', '2', 'y')
('B', '1', 'x')
('B', '1', 'y')
('B', '2', 'x')
('B', '2', 'y')
('A', '1')
('A', '2')
('B', '1')
('B', '2')
('A', 'x')
('A', 'y')
('B', 'x')
('B', 'y')
('1', 'x')
('1', 'y')
('2', 'x')
('2', 'y')
```

Comment: While I find the way you deal with start/stop somewhat strange, your answer leads essentially to the same conclusion : "Use the second parameter of combinations". Your answer provides a function that allow to easily set the min and max. However, I shouldn't need to set different values of min/max depending on my data and can deal with that by just limiting it with a min(maxsize, len(lists)) in the call to range. Thx for your answer and the demo :)

Comment: @sildar: the `start` and `stop` handling is based on how `range()` handles this, but in this case it may be overcomplicated a little. I'll simplify.