# How can I get Cartesian products of some subsets of my lists, as well as the product of the entire list of lists?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, cartesian-product

It's probably on Google, but I'm having a hard time putting into words what I'm trying to do. itertools.product is close, but I also want it to give me smaller combinations whereas itertools only gives combinations across all lists. It would probably be easier to explain in an example:

Example of lists I want to combine:
[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]

Itertools gives back:
[a,d,g],[a,d,h]....[c,f,h],[c,f,i] (27 results)

Output I am looking for:
The above, plus:

[a,d],[a,e],[a,f],[b,d],[b,e],[b,f],[c,d],[c,e],[c,f],[d,g],[d,h],[d,i],[e,g],[e,h],[e,i],[f,g],[f,h],[f,i]

There would be a total of 45 results. Note that I'm only looking for combinations between the lists that are next to each other (don't want [a,g] returned). The lists will not be this simple either, there will be a set of 10 lists with 3-4 characters each.

The only line of code I have for this is:
list(itertools.product(*thelist))]. I just don't know where to go next on what I'm trying to do here. I have a feeling there's some way to do this with itertools, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried using `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: I tried briefly, but was having difficulty, maybe wasn't implementing it right with the 2D lists. I'm going to play with itertools.combinations some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to run `itertools.product` on each sublist of your list of lists, and concatenate the results of that together.

Does the following do what you need?

```py
import itertools

def combine(lists, min_length):
    items = []
    for start in range(len(lists)):
        for end in range(start + min_length, len(lists) + 1):
            items.extend(itertools.product(*lists[start:end]))
            
    return items
```

I called this function using the following:

```py
combine([["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]], 2)
```

and it returned a list of 45 tuples, which appeared to contain all of the items you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You have the first 27.  Here is how you get the other 18:

```
import itertools as it
lst = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]

result = [it.product(lst[i], lst[i+1]) for i in range(len(lst)-1)]
result = list(it.chain.from_iterable(result))

print(result)
#[('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('a', 'f'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('c', 'f'), ('d', 'g'), ('d', 'h'), ('d', 'i'), ('e', 'g'), ('e', 'h'), ('e', 'i'), ('f', 'g'), ('f', 'h'), ('f', 'i')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using pretty clever bit checking method from [HERE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/147636)

```py
from itertools import product

x = ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')

def subsets(s):
    sets = []
    for i in range(1, 1 << len(s)):
        if bin(i).count("1") != 1 and '11' in bin(i):
            subset = [s[bit] for bit in range(len(s)) if is_bit_set(i, bit)]
            sets.append(subset)
    return sets

def is_bit_set(num, bit):
    return num & (1 << bit) > 0

a = 0
super_sets = subsets(x)
for sset in super_sets:
    a += len(list(product(*sset)))
    #print(list(product(*sset)))
print(a)
```

> 54