# Using pure numpy instead of multiple nested for loops that include a calculation with changing values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, cartesian-product

The following function uses nested for loops that include a calculation used to populate a numpy array:

```py
def foo():
  # Initializing variables
  xrange = 2
  yrange = 2
  t_array = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(3, 5))
  const_var = 1 
  output_array = np.zeros((xrange, yrange, t_array.shape[1]))
  dist = np.zeros(t_array.shape[1])                                                                                                                                                                                  

  # Populating output_array
  for x in range(xrange):                                                                                                                                                                                                            
              for y in range(yrange):                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                  for x1 in range(const_var):                                                                                                                                                                                               
                      for y1 in range(const_var):                                                                                                                                                                                           
                          for i in range(t_array.shape[1]):                                                                                                                                                                              
                              dist[i] = (x+x1)*(y+y1)+const_var                                                                                                                               
                          output_array[x,y,np.argmin(dist)] = output_array[x,y,np.argmin(dist)] + 1
  return output_array
```

**Is there a general way to do this in pure numpy without using for loops?**

Additional explanation:

The first four for loops calculate their Cartesian product. The fifth for loop populates `dist` with the values from the iterators of the first four for loops. Once `dist` is populated, the output array gets updated at the respective indices with the values of the first four iterators and the index of the smallest value from `dist`. The final result should be a populated `output_array`.

I would like to do this in pure numpy as it would be much faster. My main problem is that the values used in the calculation for `dist` (`x`,`x1`,`y`,`y1`) change according to the iterations of the first four for loops and I do not know how to account for this using pure numpy.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221721/cartesian-product-of-different-size), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66789371/how-can-i-get-cartesian-products-of-some-subsets-of-my-lists-as-well-as-the-pro)? Are these of any help?

Comment: Could you update your example so that it is reproducible? output_array is misspelled and the v3 array doesn't exist. Also I'm having a tough time figuring out what you're trying to do. Could you provide some context? Also it would be helpful if you could shrink the size of your arrays as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you @IgnatiusReilly for the links. I will look into them as I thought of `itertools.product` as an alternative to explore if numpy doesn't work for this.

Thank you @Tyson for the valuable feedback and the justified critique. I made the example reproducible and less specific, shrunk the arrays, fixed the typos and added an additional explanation. I hope that makes things less convoluted and clearer what my intention is.

Comment: Yes this is much better. Thank you. I will give this a whirl later and see if I can figure something out.